# Form renderer for PHP

Tags: php, forms, rendering

I tried the Drupal form APIs and like it a lot.  What stand-alone PHP classes exist that perform similar functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/ is a pretty good php form builder class.

Handles all the usual form needs plus captcha, google map, jquery UI integration and some others.

Comment: Does not appear to be so, seems to be its own project which incorporated Jquery UI.  

Only problem I have found with it is its lack of using for attribute on labels.  I have posted on their google group about this but yet to receive a response.  (it is a big deal for me at OSU because we have to be 508 compliant on all projects.)

Comment: I think i saw labels in the examples.  I have requirement for client side mobile devices.  Is the client-side javascript code optional/removable?

Comment: Labels do come in examples but they do not use the for attribute to attach a label to a given form field.  I will post an update if i figure out how or get response on google group.

http://groups.google.com/group/php-form-builder-class/browse_thread/thread/2580af35383e73c3

Comment: I didn't like this class. Had too many limitations and I ended up having to hack it's source apart.